# Can't go into Google Drive directory mounted with rclone: "Transport endpoint is not connected"

Tags: mount, unmount, rclone

`ls -l` shows:

```
ls: cannot access 'gdrive-root': Transport endpoint is not connected
total 42M
d?????????   ? ?         ?            ?            ? gdrive-root
```

Trying to re-mount with the command used initially also throws the same error:

```
$ rclone --vfs-cache-mode writes mount gdrive: gdrive-root --daemon
2022/01/30 15:29:14 Fatal error: Can not open: gdrive-root: open gdrive-root: transport endpoint is not connected
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found [the solution on the `rclone` forum](https://forum.rclone.org/t/how-to-unmount-and-remount-google-shared-drives-on-ultraseedbox/19174/2?u=toraritte):

1. Unmount with `fusermount -uz gdrive-root`
2. Re-mount with the command you usually use (in my case, it's in the question above)

---

Update from @[nnunes](https://superuser.com/users/525410/nnunes):

> Using `fusermount -z ...` means "*the mount point is no longer associated with the mount, but the mount doesn't disappear until all open files on that mount are closed*" ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313902/144498)).

Comment: Using `fusermount -z ...` means _"the mount point is no longer associated with the mount, but the mount doesn't disappear until all open files on that mount are closed"_ ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313902/144498)).

Comment: @nnunes Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

umount command worked when fusermount failed for me:

```
umount -l  /PATH/MOUNTED
```

See: https://syntaxfix.com/question/8248/transport-endpoint-is-not-connected

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).